# A4 PDF Financial Reports - using python / markdown / html-css

Tags: python, html, markdown

As an accountant, I produce A4 PDF financial reports for clients. The report contains a PDF cover page design, table of contents, blocks of text and many tables of financial data.

To date I have used a mixture of Microsoft Excel and Word to produce these reports, then save as PDF and add the PDF cover. The major disadvantages to this are that I have to manually edit the tables, I would much rather create automated reports based off existing data exported from my accounting software.

I would like to move away from Excel-Word and move towards (semi-) automating this through python (potentially pandas and markdown packages) - with markdown or html.

Previously I used LaTeX to produce these reports, however I found LaTeX challenging if something went wrong, the errors are difficult to understand and even basic table production can be challenging.

I am trying to plan out how I could bring together python-markdown-html/css. I was wondering if anyone else had experience in producing A4 reports in this way and any advice that they could offer. Initially I was drawn to having text saved as .md files and data stored in either mongoDB, pandas dataframes or simply CSV. I would then use the combination of .md and the data to produce a complete report in HTML. However, could HTML be converted into A4 PDF easily? I understand that there are now page CSS functionality for printing, but is this applicable? How would you suggest I can automate the creation of A4 PDF reports?

Comment: While you don't explicitly ask for recommendations, any answer I would give would basically include a list of various pieces of software I would stitch together to accomplish your end goal. And software recommendations are off-topic here. I would suggest focusing your question on one single step of the entire process. You may need to ask multiple questions along the way.

Comment: Coming back to this question two years on, I have found the reportlab Python library very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions plainly:

However, could HTML be converted into A4 PDF easily?

Yes, this is possible using pandoc.

I understand that there are now page CSS functionality for printing, but is this applicable?

Not needed if you use a pandoc template, but possible if desired.

How would you suggest I can automate the creation of A4 PDF reports?

I suggest using pandoc and pandoc templates. This will allow you to convert from a file containing a mixture of makdown, latex, html, and whatever else you would like directly into a pdf.

More details on how:

[Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) is a document conversion tool that can do this job very well. It will allow you to convert from html or markdown or LaTeX or a mix of all 3 into pdf or a number of other desired formats. For additional control on how the output looks, you can use a [pandoc template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates). You can find information on how to create a custom template [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates). Here is an example of how that command works:

pandoc /filepath/doc_name.md -o doc_name.pdf --template /file_path/pandoc-templates/article.latex

This process can automated with some further effort. You could do something such as write some python code to generate your graphs or tables from source csv files, then have that code call your pandoc command and build a document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I convert my ipython files with graphics outputs and tables into nice looking PDF files, hiding the code segments:

1. First install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions with

`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

and wkhtmltopdf library from:

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html for example I use macos so I had to install

- wkhtmltox-0.12.6-2.macos-cocoa.pkg

from this site.

2. Now convert your file outputs to HTML hiding your code:

`jupyter nbconvert --no-input --to html A4_REPORT.ipynb`

(A4_REPORT.ipynb is the file you should already have prepared generating some kind of a table, graph or have contained inline markdown segments and able to run in jupyter notebook)

3. Now convert your this HTML to PDF:

`wkhtmltopdf A4_REPORT.html A4_REPORT.pdf`

DONE !